# PHP PDO Logging Into Account

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

function login($database, $username, $password) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=':username'";
$query = $database->prepare($query);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username));

$rowcount = $query->rowCount();

    if($rowcount == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $dbPass      = $row["password"];


            if($password == $dbPass){
                session_start();

                $dbId        = $row["id"];
                $dbUser      = $row["username"];
                $dbEmail     = $row["email"];
                $dbFirstname = $row["firstname"];
                $dbLastname  = $row["lastname"];

                        //Register Session Variables
                $_SESSION['id']        = $dbId;
                $_SESSION['username']  = $dbUser;
                $_SESSION['email']     = $dbEmail;
                $_SESSION['name']      = $dbFirstname." ".$dbLastname;

                return true;

            } else
                return false;
    } else
        return false;
}

?>
```

This is a PHP code snippet from a project I am globally converting to PDO. This is the functions.php file for the login page. Obviously it is not fully converted to PDO so don't criticize that, but basically in the login.php file I have it access this method, and pass the database(which is required in), the username, and the password from the form. I setup a basic query to find all users with the username input of the form. Then i prepare, and execute the query. I then need a row count, so I setup a $rowcount variable running the rowCount() method on the query, but the code does not move past there. The rowcount is == 0 when I echo it out so it won't proceed to the following if statement. Am I doing something wrong with the PDO or something? Or the rowCount(). My suspicion is that perhaps I am calling the rowCount() too late, so I tried moving it up before I execute the $query but no luck. Thank you!

**___EDIT___**

```
<?php
session_start();


function login($database, $username, $password) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=':username'";
$query = $database->prepare($query);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username));

    if($query->rowCount()){
        $row = $query->fetch();
        echo $row;
        $dbPass      = $row["password"];


            if($password == $dbPass){

                $dbId        = $row["id"];
                $dbUser      = $row["username"];
                $dbEmail     = $row["email"];
                $dbFirstname = $row["firstname"];
                $dbLastname  = $row["lastname"];

                        //Register Session Variables
                $_SESSION['id']        = $dbId;
                $_SESSION['username']  = $dbUser;
                $_SESSION['email']     = $dbEmail;
                $_SESSION['name']      = $dbFirstname." ".$dbLastname;

                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Again I know that I am using mysql() code after the if statement, but my problem now is that I cannot even get the code to run the if statement.

Comment: You can't mix them like that.

Comment: `Obviously it is not fully converted to PDO` - It's pointless posting this as a question then.

Comment: Alright, I changed the first line in the if statement to $row = $query->fetch(); but still no luck. For whatever reason, I can't get the rowCount() to correctly register.

Comment: For a start `rowCount()` is not reliable with `SELECT`[**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @davidstrachan: `"not guaranteed for all databases"`, it works as expected for MySQL though.

Comment: @davidstrachan the question is tagged in mysql, and it is known that mysql can be relied on for that.

Comment: Besides the answer(s) given, remove the quotes `WHERE username=':username'";`

Comment: As an aside, you should hash your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't mix `pdo` and `mysql_` functions together. NEVER!

#### Don't store `password` in plain text. NEVER! Instead try [Password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/) !

#### First:

Is to replace

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);`

with

`$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

#### Second:

`session_start()` should appear at the top of your script, not inside your function.

#### Third:

Is to replace

```
   $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
   if($rowcount == 1){
     //
   }
```

with this:

`if($query->rowCount()){}`

#### Fourth:

This is BAD!!

```
           return true;

            } else
                return false;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Always, use a complete delimiter. You are instilling a bad-codding practice, that will haunt you for life.

Simple do

```
if($foo){
    if(){
       //do something
    }else if{
       //do something
    }else{
       //do something
    }
}
```

#### Fifth:

~Not good, but definitely better that your approach.

```
function small_query(pdo $pdo, $query, array $value){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($value);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(); 
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=foo', 'root', 'pass'); 

$result = small_query($pdo, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?", array($_POST['name']))
```

## EDIT.

Since you seem to love your code so much, I have done it your way. Try this:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    function login($database, $username, $password){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt  = $database->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($username));

        if($stmt->rowCount()){
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

            $_SESSION["id"] = $result["id"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $result["username"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $result["email"];

            return true; 
        }else{
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I repeat: **Don't mix pdo and mysql_ functions together. NEVER!** love it

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to edit the function in `Fifth:`?

Comment: @TheBlueDog Thanks. I have lazy eyes :)

Comment: You also missed `WHERE username=':username'";` as to "why". ;-) Plus, OP using plain text password storage.

Comment: I used the `?` place holder. Its quicker.

Comment: OP needs to be informed about the mistakes made including security issues.

Comment: @simON: I meant `(pdo $pdo, $query, array $value)` - `pdo`?

Comment: @TheBlueDog Type hinting.

Comment: @simON: I'll give you that, I was expecting `PDO`. Thought it was a copy/paste typo ;)

Comment: I would actually recommend PHP's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions for password hashing.

Comment: @MikeBrant Those are not before PHP 5.4.* I have included a link to the password_compat library.

Comment: @simON fair enough, though I would certainly favor the built-in PHP methods if running on 5.4+

Comment: @MikeBrant We all do :)

Comment: This is a test platform I am using, in the end the password will be double md5 with username salt, I am just diluting the problem down to its basics! Rowcount is not working, that is the only thing I need help with

Comment: @user3412869 Because your query is wrong.  btw: What does it mean Row count is not working? First use PDO properly, then check if something is working on not

Comment: @user3412869 Ok, check my edited answer. I think it is what you are looking for. And please accept people answer, when you find their contribution helpful.

Comment: I get what you said about the session_start() at the top of the code, but since I don't want a session to exist until session variables are registered, would it make sense to start the session only if the variables are registered? i.e., in the if statement?

And alright I adopted some of the changes you gave me @simON, but for whatever reason the rowCount doesn't exist...I can't imagine what the problem is. But now I am getting this error when I try and log in Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query()

Comment: Sorry, I meant `execute` try it now. I have update the script. and you are completely wrong about the session. it is a **BIG** No. Session is a header function. It should ALWAYS appear at the top of the script. Always. It does not do anything by itself. Session storing starts when you say `$_SESSION['something'] = 'something'` that is when the actual session get started/stored. So, you are confusing the two. Try it now and let me know @user3412869

Comment: `parepare`? it's `prepare`